# i am having issues with pub upgrade pub outdated and pub get and i am also receiving Flutter Warning

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

1. I am new to flutter and while trying to fix an issue by myself i came across this warning:****`dart` on your path resolves to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/2.19.6/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/stevesmith/flutter.** Consider adding /Users/stevesmith/flutter/bin to the front of your path.**
2. No dependencies changed.
   10 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
   Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

can anyone please simply explain to me what the issue is and how i can resolve this issue as a beginner. thank you

i have tried `flutter pub get` and `flutter update-packages`

Answer (score 0):

First of all both are warnings so you can ignore them unless you experience stuff not working.

the first one is easy to fix. Just follow the advice and add /Users/stevesmith/flutter/bin to the front of your path.

You can read more here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115651

The second warns you that packages cannot be updated because of dependencies. Its always a good idea to do this unless you explicitly know you can update a package safely.